# Is there a combined guide to install Python and PyQT with an IDE and debugger on Windows?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have found various downloads. [Here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) there is a executable "PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x64-2.exe". It says it has all you need except for Python. I presume that I have to install Python 3.5 (and not any other version?). I already have 2.7, does that mean it is not compatible?

Also, I want an IDE (but not eclipse if poss), so I have looked at [eric6](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) as suggested on a different SO question.

What I am trying to avoid is having a mess of various versions of Python, Qt libs, PyQt and an IDE that does not work/has no debugger.

Can anyone provide guidance/steps on how to integrate all these tools together?

**Note**: eric webpage say you need:

> To be able to run eric6 you should have the following installed:
>
> - Python 3.3.0 or better
> - Python 2.7.0 or better
> - Qt 5.3.0 or better (from The Qt Company)
> - Qt 4.8.0 or better (from The Qt Company)
> - PyQt 5.3.0 or better (from Riverbank)
> - PyQt 4.10.0 or better (from Riverbank)
> - QScintilla 2.8.0 or better (from Riverbank)

I find this even more confusing - does it really mean you need two different versions of Python, Qt and PyQt to be installed?

Comment: This question was marked this as off-topic by someone, but... `http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic` says you can ask questions that cover `software tools commonly used by programmers` as one of the 4 main points. I think this question fits into that category?

Comment: The close vote is because you asked to recommend an IDE/tutorial, which is off-topic for SO. But anyway, the [eric webpage](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html) you mentioned already has a very simple Windows installation guide (four lines long), so I don't really understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok, I have updated the question to just ask guidance on how to integrate all these elements. Regarding Eric, did you not see the "prerequisites? - I quoted them in my post. For example it says you need Python 3.3 or better and (or?) python 2.7 or better.... what-the-hey does that mean? :o surly installing python 3.3 covers both criteria? - so what I am asking is for a clear instruction on how to piece all these software tools together...

Comment: Seriously.... more "off-topic" votes?, I have just read the entire page of what is off/on-topic and I can't see the issue here... please can someone refer to the off-topic reason, I will/am making every effort to keep my questions within the rules - I am not a total noob here...

Comment: As is often the case with major version changes, you cannot simply upgrade directly from Python2 to Python3, or from Qt4 to Qt5. As a developer, you are expected to know this, and so it's up to you to decide which of these major versions you want/need to support. It could be either, or both - there is no "right" answer. The prerequisites simply list the minumum *minor* versions that **eric** supports for each of the components. I don't see anything unclear about any of that.

Comment: @ekhumoro, it is not clear because it does not state any of what you just wrote.. in fact that you had to write a whole paragraph to explain it infers the lack of clarity. And me being a developer has nothing to do with the price of lemons....  anyway, thanks for the clarification, +1 : )

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, the binary Windows releases for PyQt5 are Python 3 only.  The binary Windows releases for PyQt4 are available for Python2 or Python3.  Generally, you would only have one or the other (Qt4 or Qt5) installed for a given python installation.  So it would be possible to install PyQt5 to Python3 and PyQt4 to Python2.

You don't need to install both, and code written for one won't automatically work in the other anyway.

Most IDE's don't require you to install Qt/PyQt, and a lot of the guides for installing Qt/PyQt are IDE agnostic anyway.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks as a clarification, +1 : )

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmmmmm. A huge sigh. To tell you the truth, you better have a rethink about going down this path. The installation process will require you to gather many different dependencies which in the end leaves you nowhere. I have gone and come back. The rabbit hole never ends. That's how far it goes.

To make life easy for yourself, just settle for one solution. Just download Anaconda. It gives you a wonderful and nice IDE in Spyder also. Try it here:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: lol, thanks for that - I am trying to make this "one solution", like Qt/C++ download - you just run the installer and you're done, you have Qt Creator IDE integrated with Qt5.x.x, mingw compiler and all the debugger tools all ready to go. There does not seem to be this cohesion in the python world.  I'll give this a go...maybe on a test machine to start with....looks like a rather heavy install at 350mb :o but it looks the closest I have seen so for for python dev (looks like it might support pyqt as well) thanks : )

Comment: It supports PyQt as well.